# Filtering out rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have simplified a table as an example

```
   tray| food
-------+-------
     1 | fruit
     2 | veg
     2 | fruit
     2 | meat
     3 | meat
     4 | bread
```

What I want to find for each fruit, is the number of trays that ONLY contain that type of food. So the output should look like this:

```
   food| count
-------+-------
 fruit | 1
   veg | 0
  meat | 1
 bread | 1
```

I tried writing a query:

```
SELECT fruit, COUNT(*) 
FROM Inventory 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                  FROM Inventory I 
                  WHERE I.tray = tray AND I.fruit<>fruit)
GROUP BY fruit;
```

However the table returned is incorrect and it looks like my sub query is wrong but it makes logical sense to me.

```
 food  | count 
-------+-------
 fruit |     2
 veg   |     1
 bread |     1
 meat  |     2
```

It looks like tray 2 is counting once for fruit, meat and veg when it should not. But shouldn't that be ruled out by my NOT EXISTS subquery? How do I fix this?

Comment: If I'm reading your question right, you want to group by tray number, then check `HAVING COUNT(*) = 1`.

Comment: Unrelated, but: you need to fully qualify all column names in the sub-query: `where i.tray = inventory.tray`

Answer (score 0):

Clever little problem.  Here is one solution:

```
select f.food, count(t.tray)
from (select distinct food from t
     ) f left join
     (select t.tray, min(food) as minfood, max(food) as maxfood
      from tray t
      group by tray
     ) t
     on f.food = t.minfood and f.food = t.maxfood
group by f.food;
```

Getting a count of zero suggests a query where `left join` and `group by` would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
select i1.food, 
       count(ft.tray)
from inventory i1
  left join (
    select i1.tray, 
           count(distinct i1.food) as num_food
    from inventory i1
    group by i1.tray
  ) ft on i1.tray = ft.tray and num_food = 1
group by i1.food;
```

The inner query (`ft`) counts the number of different foods per tray. The outer (main) query counts the number of trays per food for those trays that only contain a single type of food.

Online example: http://rextester.com/PUN27611

Comment: I tried your query but I get an error saying column i1.food does not exist

Comment: @tenkii Well in your question you claim you have a column `food` and then you use `fruit` in the SQL example - which one is it? What is the `create table` statement for `inventory`? I used `food` in my online example

Comment: sorry the final table is suppose to be fruit, I got mixed up it in writing my example. I will try your query again in a moment as I managed to fixed my original query.